Visual Studio 2022 17.11.3 Code Cleanup on Save no longer working?
Version 17.11.3
It may be since the last update that this happened, but I have "Run Code Cleanup on Save" set. I also have this setting:
max_line_length = 120

In .editorConfig sitting at the top of the solution.
But Save document, even Format (Ctrl E + Ctrl D) does not break up my long lines.  Is there some other setting in this version of VS?
Or is there somewhere else this could be overwritten?
It is quite annoying as I really appreciate formatting on Save!



just took down 17.11.4 and I have similar issue. When saving, a loading dialog appears where it says it performs the cleanup but it never finishes..
